# refresh token is not updating into the database when working with JoeDawson/youtube package

Tags: youtube, laravel-5.3

Am working with the youtube uploading in laravel 5.3 for that am using joedawson/youtube package so when run the projectname/youtube/auth, access token is updating into the datbase but refreshtoken is not updating .

Any one let me know where the problem is going exactly with this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i got the sollution,

When we will run the projectname/youtube/auth in joedawson/youtube package it will give the access token and refresh token first time only  when we sign up with new email  but when we tried to run the same url many times it wont give the refresh token all the time it only give access token.

After some time access token will expire them the youtube video is uploaded to the channel based on refresh token,refresh token dont expire.